How to Intercept and Monitor Outgoing Notifications in Flutter Using flutter_local_notifications
I’m working on a Flutter application and using the flutter_local_notifications package to handle local notifications. I need to be able to intercept and monitor notifications before they are sent out. Specifically, I want to capture information about notifications when they are scheduled or about to be displayed, and potentially modify or log this information.
My primary goal is to record sent notifications that have not yet been read, in order to properly set the app's badge.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
Intercept Outgoing Notifications: I want to be able to intercept notifications just before they are sent out to handle any additional logic or logging.
Monitor Notification Details: Capture and log details about the notifications (e.g., title, body, payload) as they are being scheduled or shown.
Custom Handling: Implement custom handling based on the notification details before they are displayed to the user.
Badge Registration: Record sent notifications that have not yet been read to update the app's badge accordingly.
I understand that flutter_local_notifications provides callbacks for handling notifications when the user interacts with them, but I need to handle notifications before they are actually displayed.
I have tried using the show, schedule, and zonedSchedule methods but haven’t found a way to intercept notifications in the way I need.
Here’s a snippet of how I am currently scheduling notifications:
class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  NotificationService() {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    _initializeNotifications();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeNotifications() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        const DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
    );

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
          onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestNotificationsPermission();
  }

  Future<void> removeNotification(String uuid) async {
    int id = uuidToInt(uuid);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(
      String uuid, String title, String body, DateTime scheduledDate) async {
    const String channelId = 'reminder_channel';
    const String channelName = 'Reminder Notifications';
    const String channelDescription =
        'This channel is used for reminder notifications.';

    await removeNotification(uuid);

    try {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        uuidToInt(uuid),
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledDate, tz.local),
        const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channelId,
            channelName,
            channelDescription: channelDescription,
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
          ),
          iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
            sound: 'notification_sound.aiff',
          ),
        ),
        payload: uuid,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Errore durante la pianificazione della notifica: $e');
    }
  }


My Questions:
Is there a way to intercept notifications in the flutter_local_notifications package before they are sent out?
Can I add custom logic or logging for notifications at the time of scheduling or sending them?
Are there any recommended practices or alternatives for achieving this functionality in Flutter, especially for recording sent notifications that have not yet been read to manage the app’s badge?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried using the methods provided by the flutter_local_notifications package, specifically the show, schedule, and zonedSchedule methods to send notifications. My goal was to intercept and monitor these notifications before they are displayed to the user.
I expected to be able to:
Intercept Notifications Before Sending: Capture and log notification details right before they are sent out.
Monitor Notification Details: Record details of the notifications to track them for purposes such as updating the app's badge.
What actually resulted?
I was able to successfully send notifications using the aforementioned methods, but I could not find a way to intercept or monitor the notifications just before they are sent out. The package does not seem to offer built-in functionality to handle or modify notifications at this stage. Additionally, I was not able to integrate a solution to record notifications for badge management effectively.
